# how to duplicate an .xaml+cs file?

Tags: c#, xaml

What is the best method to duplicate an **.xaml+cs** file? I want to make a copy of that file but I'm afraid that there would be too many errors and that's why I've decided to ask  you.

Comment: Definitely duplicating will not be your goal, If you can say ultimate goal of what you're trying to achieve it'll be easy for us to help.

Comment: to connect the first window with the second.. basically, when the button is clicked, a new copy should open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it but I am Assuming That You want as it is copy with different Name and using Visual Studio.

1) right click on your xml file in Project Explorer

2)choose copy

3)right click

4)choose past.

it will appear as copy of yourxml file.

5) rename it as desired...

hope this is help full.